# Ruby newline use of two \n

Tags: ruby

I have a question about the need for the use of \n\n to make a newline.
Please see below examples.

If I do ..

```
puts "hello"
puts "hi"
```

or

```
puts "hello\n"
puts "hi"
```

The output is..

```
hello  
hi
```

If I do ..

```
puts "hello\n\n"
puts "hi"
```

The output is..

```
hello

hi
```

Why do I need `\n\n` to make one extra newline?
Why doesn't the single `\n` make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `puts` is to ensure the string ends with the newline character.

- If there is none, then one newline character will be appended.
- If there is one or more, no newline character will be appended.

Comment: Thanks sawa and other responders - Got it now.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> #### puts(obj, ...) → nil
>
> Writes the given objects to ios as with `IO#print`. **Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence.** If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here nailed it.

If you want to avoid the magic handling of \n, try using `print` instead of `puts`.  `print` outputs your string literally, with no line ending unless you put it there.

```
> 3.times { print 'Zap' }
ZapZapZap=> 3
> 3.times { puts 'Zap' }
Zap
Zap
Zap
=> 3
```